# How to handle continous GET requests?

Tags: c#, get, aforge, ip-camera

I am working on a little Windows Form Application, that shows me the streams of several IP Cameras (from different companies) in my Network and also allows me to move the Cameras (left,right,up,down,zoom). This is realised with AFORGE.net MJPEG Streams and the camera movements through firing get requests.
Problem: I have one camera that doesn't move in steps (after each click on 'up' for example) but it moves continuously. It only stops when I send another request with the parameter 'stop'.

GET Request to Move Right:

```
http://192.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX/web/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=right&-speed=63
```

GET Request to Stop the movement:

```
http://192.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX/web/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-                                                               act=stop&-speed=63
```

Function I use for the other Cameras:

```
private void move_right()
    {
    string url = 'someURL';
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.GetResponse();
    request.Abort(); 
    }
```

I would like the camera to move right stepwise after clicking a button, but when firing the request to move right, my program just gets stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HttpClient object and create an asynchronous request, try something like (untested):

```
private async Task move_right()
{
    var url = 'someURL';
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage() 
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(url),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    };

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    //Do something with your response
}

private async Task executeWebRequests() 
{
    //Usage - Await for result
    await move_right();

    //Execute asynchronously
    move_right(); //Will create a new task and run asynchronously in the BG
    move_right(); //Will create a new task and run asynchronously in the BG
    move_right(); //Will create a new task and run asynchronously in the BG
    move_right(); //Will create a new task and run asynchronously in the BG
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a camera using the same url.

This thread is a few years old, but for anyone else interested, use step=1 to move stepwise.

[image: ptz control]